# Linux / C++ : memory is not fully released when threads end

Tags: c++, multithreading

Ubuntu 18.04 on an Intel i7

The following code starts 5 threads in sequence, then sleeps 60 seconds before quitting.
Each thread allocates 1 MB memory via malloc, then frees it immediately, then sleeps 10 seconds then returns.

When the threads end one thinks that the memory would be fully released to the OS.
Top and /proc/(pid)/smaps both show that after the threads return, the memory is still reserved to main and not available for other processes running on the same computer.

Is that normal behaviour?

````
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define HOWMANY 5 

void* threadFct(void*);

int main()
{
        int threadCounter;
        pthread_t tId;

        threadCounter = 0;

        while(threadCounter < HOWMANY)
        {
                sleep(1);
                std::cerr << "THREAD " << std::hex << pthread_self() << " creating thread " << std::dec << threadCounter << std::endl;
                int error = pthread_create(&tId, NULL, threadFct, NULL);
                threadCounter++;
                if (error == 0)
                        pthread_detach(tId);
        }

        sleep(60);
}

void* threadFct(void*)
{
        uint32_t dim = 1024*1024;
        char *buff = (char*)malloc(dim);
        if (buff != NULL)
        {
                std::cerr << "THREAD " << std::hex << pthread_self() << " got memory at address " << (void*) buff << " filling buffer... ";
                for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
                        buff[i] = (char)(rand() % 256);
                std::cerr << "done" << std::endl;
        }
        else
                std::cerr << "THREAD " << std::hex << pthread_self() << " malloc failed" << std::endl;

        if (buff != NULL) free(buff);
        sleep(10);
        std::cerr << "THREAD " << std::hex << pthread_self() << " exiting" << std::endl;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}```
````

Comment: Yes, memory is only released back to the O/S when the process ends.

Comment: "_When the threads end one thinks that the memory would be fully released to the OS_" - **I** don't think so. The process may need it again.

Comment: Why would using _threads_ make a difference here? Memory is generally pooled on a per-process basis

Comment: I am asking this question because there are cases where the memory allocated to threads is actually released when threads end. In the example above, if in threadFct I make the thread sleep *before* I free the buffer, instead of the opposite, then on my computer both top and smaps report that the memory reserved to the process shrinks from 6 MB down to 2 MB when the threads end, instead of staying at 6 MB until the process terminates.

Comment: free()/or delete release the memory to the heap, not to the kernel. Memory can be given back to OS if the freed chuck is at the top of the data segment allocated by the process. Or, free() can do some shuffling internally to move the chuck at top and then release the memory to OS but it would be a very costly operation. So, this is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, every process have a virtual view of memory and work with it, process have a stack memory and heap memory and we can change size of heap with functions like `malloc()` or directly using functions like `sbrk()`. When we request a block of memory the size of heap get larger.

Let's imagine this is your process heap memory which every thread used one megabyte of it:

```
Heap
+------
|  +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  | thread_1 | thread_2 | thread_3 | thread_4 | thread_5 |
   +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
       1MB         1MB        1MB       1MB         1MB
```

So here if `thread_2` done it's job and it's ready to terminate, what is happen for it's allocated memory on heap ? It's depend on if process need again to allocate another 1MB on the heap, the `thread_2` released memory is use; but if process request more, the heap size get larger:

```
Heap
+------
|  +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|  | thread_1 | ???????? | thread_3 | thread_4 | thread_5 | for_others |
   +----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+------------+
       1MB         1MB        1MB       1MB         1MB        3MB
```

On process destruction memory will be freed and available to OS.

---

I think these could be useful:

- https://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/
- https://man7.org/tlpi/